# Error: templated copy constructor calls itself

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

when this copy constructor is called in my application, this copy constructor goes into an infinite loop i.e it keeps calling itself.
When i debugged the pogram terminated at the first line itself.
The foreach loop used is a Qt foreach.

```
template<class TValue>
Locus<TValue>::Locus (const Locus<TValue>& source ) : QVector<TValue>(source) // program terminates here
{
    std::cout << "calling self from here " << std::endl;
    foreach (typename Locus<TValue>::value_type l, source)
    {
        this->push_back(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor isn't templated. It's just an ordinary function (as much as a constructor can be called that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword):

> Qt automatically takes a copy of the container when it enters a foreach loop.

Comment: @shobi: I don't know the Qt API, but the solution would be to use something that doesn't take a copy of `source`.  Perhaps a normal loop?

Comment: ok so u mean to say that Qt foreach takes the copy of source, so what about BOOST_FOREACH

Comment: @shobi: The ideal case is to not write a copy-constructor at all.  What does `this->push_back` do?

Comment: @shobi: QVector's copy constructor already "copies" (copy-on-write) the contents of the source, you don't need that loop at all unless you want a deep copy - and if you do, you shouldn't be calling `QVector`'s copy constructor. Use a plain iterator loop rather than `foreach` if you really want to. (And don't "advertise" your question by comment pinging people, it's annoying.)